# Why my callback function runs every time even when false?

Tags: javascript, callback

I am learning callbacks but I think I made a mistake somewhere but not sure why following is my code. The code works in both cases even when the URL is wrong or has typo and there is twice Error is console.

```
function getTodos(callback){
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.addEventListener("readystatechange", function(){
        if(request.readyState === 4){
            callback(undefined, console.log(request.responseText))
        }else{
            callback("Error")
        }
    })
    request.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
    request.send();
}

getTodos(function callback(err, data){
   if(err){
       console.log(err)
   }else{
       console.log(data);
   }
});
```

It took me days to understand it but not sure if I got it right.

Comment: What is the question? What goes wrong?

Comment: That is because the `readystatechange` event is fired multiple times for the same request (every time `readyState` changes).

Comment: `console.log()` returns undefined ... so your data never gets passed to the callback when request succeeds

Answer (score 0):

Ready state 4 would indicate that you are done with your request. This example will show you the various levels of readyState.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log('UNSENT', xhr.readyState); // readyState will be 0

xhr.open('GET', '/api', true);
console.log('OPENED', xhr.readyState); // readyState will be 1

xhr.onprogress = function () {
    console.log('LOADING', xhr.readyState); // readyState will be 3
};

xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log('DONE', xhr.readyState); // readyState will be 4
};

xhr.send(null);
```

More information can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState

When using a callback, here is a simple function that takes in a username, and a callback function, this function will use setState to set the current state, then it will run its callback function, since I will call it after setState.

```
function one(username, blah) {
   this.setState({
       username: username 
   })
   blah()
}
```

So now you have your function ready, it will take in a username setState and then run ANY function passed in when called.

```
function two() {
 console.log('WOOOHOO We got a username and set state');
}
function three() {
 console.log('O joy we got a username');
}
```

Now I will show you calling you function.

```
one('Bob', two) // Output: WOOOHOO We got a username and set state
one('Bob', three) // O joy we got a username
```

As you can see we are calling the same function 'one' but the functions passed in are different in the two examples.

Comment: ah, now I know. but besides that my callbacks r fine? It hard to understand the concept.

Comment: Not exactly, when you are making a callback, you should pass in your parameters, then a callback function myFunction(username, yourFunction) { //do what you need then yourFunction()} Using said code, yourFunction will be any function passed in as a parameter AFTER  a username when  you call this  function.  Like so myFunction('Bob', anotherFunctionNotShownHere) , so, when you do this, you   are passing Bob as the username and then your function runs....hope this helps..

Comment: can u update ur answer to add this as It is hard to read in comment